# Flash animation in OpenLayers is not continously rendered

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using Open Layers 5 to show a flashing animation for points in a map.
The animation should restart after a random, limited amount of time. In order to do this, I added a timeout function that calls the animation function after about 3 seconds.

The code is similar to the open layers example:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-animation.html
The only difference is that I do not add features in the interval, I set a timer for each feature that runs the animation.

The first time the feature is added I can see the animation, but afterwards it doesn't seem to be rendered anymore. 
The animation shows only when dragging the map, so I'm guessing that the map isn't automatically rendered when it's running on the timeout thread, even though map.render is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a feature is added the map will automatically re-render so the flash function doesn't need to force an initial render.  If flash is to be called randomly you will need to force a render after setting the listener.

```
var listenerKey = map.on('postcompose', animate);
map.render();
```